# Windows 2012 roll up update fails to install, and then will not reinstall

Tags: windows, windows-update

I am having a problem with one Win2012-R2 server. All the others updated fine, but on this system, the security update 2017-12 failed to install.

I have rebooted the system and tried to manually force "check for updates."

How do I get this update to install?

[image]

Comment: Download it from the Microsoft Update Catalog and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the link "Check online updates from Windows Update"

That did the trick. The path through our internal update server was not working for some reason (just for this update, on this system)

Comment: Actually, IMHO this should not be considered as a solution if you're deploying updates with the help of WSUS! Anyway, good to know that doing this worked for you.